# Selecting app from multitask menu makes app disappear

Tags: android

On multiple occasions I have been testing the app, leave the app by pressing the home button and when I return to my device later I press the multitask button and select MyAPP from the list of recent apps and the app just disappears.

```
ActivityManager(270): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10095
```

Only above line i have found that is wondering me. I also when select Back Button on my device, Application didn't load (didn't show previous activity in stack).
Is there android operating system that cause this to pull out from the Stack?
How can i omit this issue?

Answer (score 0):

maybe that activity has flag   `android:excludeFromRecents=["true" | "false"]`

Comment: Do you mean ,when i start new activity,may i have set excludeFromRecents flag??

Comment: yes. by doing this to all your activities, your application will not be showed in recents app list. These flags are set by developers in their code(your app code).

Comment: i am not using excludeFromRecents